# IE 8 Z-index stacking issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index

http://carettaworkspace.spirecms.com

In IE 8, the text and thumbnail image within the buttons to the right of the slideshow are stacking above the empty  areas which can be clicked to control the slideshow.  In other browsers, the entire area is clickable within the button to change slides.

I know IE 7 & 8 are special when it comes to Z-index stacking, and I've tried many of the common fixes (setting a z-index to the parent divs, positioning parent divs different ways), but I am unable to fix the problem.  Does anyone know of a solution that could fix this issue?

So you know, the text and image of the slideshow are under the slidethumbs div.  The empty links can be found under the slidearea -> anythingControls div.

Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was two part: First, I needed to reorder the HTML a bit to get the two problem layers under the same parent div. This allowed me to set a z-index for the parent div as well as the child divs to make IE play nice. Secondly, I found that IE would not allow an empty  div to function above text or images! Weird. So, I ended up giving the  div a 1px x 1px non-repeating background image so it technically wasn't completely empty. This completely fixed the issue, and IE8 allowed the  div to be above the image and text areas.

Comment: or just add `&nbsp;` to the div

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can without re-ordering a bit of your HTML / CSS.  Haven't looked at it in IE (on a mac), but here's the explanation:

In IE, stacking context is defined by ***anything*** with `position` set.  So your `.anythingSlider` is defining a stacking context and your nav ul can't get above the thumbnails.

Basically, z-index only goes up to the nearest element with a stacking context.  In most browsers context is defined by anything with (positioning + z-index) or (opacity < 1).

FYI, what I normally do is set `z-index: 1` on *everything* that has positioning set.  It's a bit more annoying to deal with, but all the browsers behave the same that way.

Comment: OK, I'll try to see if reordering my HTML works and will respond when done.

Comment: Yes, this was half of the solution!  Thank you!